# How to configure dynamic height for UILabel in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, height

I am trying to setup UILabel in view controller with dynamic height so that it fits according to the text.

I tried various examples available on stack overflow but to no good yet.

is there any other specific method for Swift 5 to make UILabel height dynamic?

[UI Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KY5y.png)

[View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPz5t.png)

Comment: use autolayout https://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/using-autolayout-to-dynamically-resize-uilabel/

Comment: @jamil I tried it already but it didn't worked

Comment: did you set the label.numofLines = 0 ?

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: @CZ54 yes I did set number of lines to 0 in storyboard

Answer (score 2):

1) set the top/leading/trailing constraints of the label to superview/Safe Area.
2) set the numberOfLines = 0 in the attribute inspector for the label in the storyboard.

Comment: it still not working, I tried and now it is showing nothing

Comment: can you add the screenshots of the storyboard with the attributes inspector pane open.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the HeightConstraint of label from storyboard and add 0 in number of lines your label will get the text and set as per content.

Comment: it still not working, I tried and now it is showing nothing

Answer (score 1):

In your UIConstraints I can see height constraint = 134, remove height constraint to dynamically adjust the height of your label.

Pragmatically you can achieve this by code below

```
let myLabel = UILabel()
        self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
        myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([myLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
        myLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
        myLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30)])
        myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        myLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        myLabel.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "
```

Comment: it still not working, I tried and now it is showing nothing

Comment: check by setting vertical content hugging priority to 250
and set vertical compression resistance to 751.

Comment: But still now working, I have started it on fresh layout as well, but still the same problem, I removed all other elements and yet no success, I don't why Xcode behaves so stupidly sometimes, following all the guidelines accordingly and still the same stupidity happens, I am trying to resolve this for past 3 days, I know it is a simple thing but yet no success

Comment: @Ramneek can you check by adding above code in your ViewDidLoad method. I have edited my answer.

Comment: sure, let me check

Answer (score 0):

Give your `UILabel`, `leading`, `trailing` and `top` constraints. Don't give `bottom` constraints. If you have to give `bottom` constraints, don't give `top` constraint.

Also, set `numberOfLines = 0`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var yourLabel : UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not working, after I removed the bottom constraint, now it doesn't even show it

Comment: have you give the top constraint?

Comment: @Ramneek share your UI and constraints. edit your question

Comment: I have shared the UI constraints again , please check

Comment: @Ramneek remove the height constraint

Comment: I have already given the solution. There is something wrong in your layout or code maybe. Your label might be hiding behind any other view.

Comment: I have added the view controller, should I start it again according to the guidelines to resolve the issue?

Comment: @jawadAli it still not working, I tried and now it is showing nothing

Comment: share your project ... i will see and fix that for you

Answer (score 0):

Specify numberOfLines = 0 and in label height constraints specify like greater than or equal to zero.